# First row i scroll table is not responding to user input

Tags: java

First row in a scroll table is not responding to user input when we click on that row while remaining all rows are working fine in java.

explanation :  I have a scroll table consisting of 3 columns and 8 rows, when I try to select first row in the table it is not responding i.e., the first row is not getting selected while the remaining 7 rows are working fine responding to user inputs and are selected when we click on that row

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MegaTron : I have a scroll table consisting of 3 columns and 8 rows, when I try to select first row in the table it is not responding i.e., the first row is not getting selected while the remaining 7 rows are working fine responding to user inputs and are selected when we click on that row.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information

Comment: @MegaTron :  I have edited my question using edit link

Comment: It's not enough, we need code to help you.

Comment: @AfrozKhanam ok, great and now read again [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want help